# Select And Allow Ref(null) Result From Object Table

Tags: oracle, plsql, refs

I'd like to run a function that will select a ref into an attribute from an object table, and if the table returns null then the attribute is set to null. To achieve this I tried the code.

```
select ref(t) into self_ref from my_table where objectID = self.objectID;
```

But this fails anytime that the where fails to find a match. In place I have the following

```
select count(*)
    into l_result
    from my_table
 where companyID = self.companyID;
if l_result > 0 then
    select ref(t)
        into self_ref
        from my_table t
     where objectID = self.objectID;
else
    self_ref := null;
end if;
```

But I'd like if there was a better solution that didn't involve so much redundancy.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conventional approach (whether you're dealing with object references or any other local variable) would be

```
begin
  select ref(t)
    into self_ref
    from my_table t
   where objectID = self.objectID;
exception
  when no_data_found
  then
    self_ref := null;
end;
```

This avoids the potential race condition where the `count(*)` returns a different result than the subsequent `select`.  Technically, assuming you've never assigned a value to `self_ref` previously, it would already be `null` so your exception handler could simply ignore the `no_data_found` exception.  I prefer to do the explicit assignment of the variable to `null` even though it's technically redundant, however, because it tends to make the code clearer.  Subsequent maintainers don't have to question whether you intended to set (or leave) the local variable `null` if you do it explicitly.

You could construct this various other ways as well, for example

```
self_ref := null;
for r in (select ref(t) my_ref
            from my_table t
           where objectID = self.objectID)
loop
  self_ref := r.my_ref;
end loop;
```

but the `select into` with an exception handler would be the most common and would most accurately express your intention.